# Error using the attr function with href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the error `undefined is not a function` when running this code:

```
var links=$("li").find("a");//this works...has a length of 23
//then I run this
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
  links[i].attr("href");//this does not work
}
```

What can I do to obtain to get the href property from the link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The elements of a jQuery object are DOM elements, not other jQuery objects, so they don't have jQuery methods. You can use the [`eq` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to access jQuery-wrapped versions of those elements:

```
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    href = links.eq(i).attr("href");
}
```

Or just access the property directly:

```
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
    href = links[i].href;
}
```

In your example code you're not actually doing anything with the value though so you may want to sort that out too.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply try :

```
$("li a").each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Or fix your code to create a jquery object to be able to use attr function :

```
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
  $(links[i]).attr("href");
}
```

Or simply use href :

```
  links[i].href;
```

Comment: I had no clue that jQuery has the each function baked into it.